# What is the correct way to accessing React App from Nginx proxy

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I wrote a React application, I want to make it reachable as application deployed on a Web Nginx server, the application have a link at Reat App. To do this I configured an reverse proxy inside Nginx. My problem is the when I call the Node/React app by the link I only see a white page, all works perfectly in the Browser if I call the Node/React app directly.
See below:

> package.json (server)

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "engines": {
    "node": "9.8.0",
    "npm": "6.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.1.4",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.5"
  }
}
```

> index.js (server)

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const keys = require('./config/Keys');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
require('./models/User');
require('./models/Profile');
mongoose.connect(keys.mongoURI);
const User =  mongoose.model('users');

 app.use(express.static('client/build'));
  const path = require('path');
  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname,'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
  });
```

> package.json (client)

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": ".",
  "proxy": {
    "/api/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:5000"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "redux": "^4.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

> index.js (client)

```
import materializeCSS from 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';  
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import App from './components/App';
const store = createStore(() => [], {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

   ReactDOM.render(
   <Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>,
    document.querySelector('#root'));
```

> Nginix reverse proxy

`location /react {

```
            proxy_pass http://10.30.1.185:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }`
```

[image: screenshot from 2018-06-08 15-04-59]

[image: screenshot from 2018-06-08 15-05-16]

In the Browswer console I get the following warning:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://snapmed.ca/static/js/main.cfe29440.js”.
```

Any thoughts why I am getting just a white page?

Answer (score 4):

You should not be using `npm start` for an nginx deploy of a React app. Use `npm run build` to convert your React application into static files, then simply point nginx to that directory. Once built, you no longer have to use `npm start`.

`npm start` is for deploying a local development server. The development server monitors for file changes as you are developing so that it can reload the page in response to changes. This is not relevant to an nginx deploy of your application.

`npm run build` concatenates, bundles, and otherwise optimizes your files for deploy on a real server, not a development server. Once bundled, there is no need for the development server to be running -- the static files alone have all the correct references to each other and no longer need to reload live as files change.

It appears you are currently pointing your nginx server to a development server (port 5000). You should not be doing this. Your nginx server should point simply to the directly where the built React app resides (typically a `build` directory is added to the same directory from which you run `npm run build`). You can point nginx to this directory using the `root` keyword instead of using the proxy keywords.

Comment: Hi @Charkes, React application must to run in node.

Comment: No, a React application does _not_ need to be run in Node. The developer environment for create-react-app uses Node for live reloading. The production build uses _static, flat_ files that are meant to be delivered by a server such as nginx. There is absolutely no Node required for a production-facing React application, and using Node will _decrease_ the quality of your distribution by having the unnecessary Node overhead.

Use `npm run build`, and it will output a `./build/` directory with static files. Those are the files that you should point nginx toward, not your Node development port.